# using withDefault() on belongsTo results in error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
public function featuredimage()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Image::class, 'featured_image_id')->withDefault();
}
```

this gives me: Call to undefined relationship [featuredimage] on model [App\Models\Core\Blog\Post].

any ideas why?

it should work according to docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

> Default Models
>
> The belongsTo relationship allows you to define a default model that
>   will be returned if the given relationship is null. This pattern is
>   often referred to as the Null Object pattern and can help remove
>   conditional checks in your code. In the following example, the user
>   relation will return an empty  App\User model if no user is attached
>   to the post:
>
> ```
> public function user()
> {
>     return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withDefault();
> }
> ```

my laravel version: 5.4.27

I have two tables:

posts table and images table

inside post table I do this:

```
$table->biginteger('featured_image_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

$table->foreign('featured_image_id')->references('id')->on('images')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: can you share your database design ?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: and your images table ?

Comment: try this `return $this->belongsTo(Image::class, 'featured_image_id', 'id')->withDefault();`

Comment: Where do you place your `image.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to upgrade to the latest laravel version as the `withDefault` method is available as from 5.4.28.

To update, simply run:

```
composer update
```